# May a postdoc propose, design, and lecture his graduate-level course?

Tags: postdocs, course-design

I'll be starting a postdoc position in a Canadian institute soon. However, I could not secure any independent lectureship in the course of my contract interval (but just a limited joint lectureship with my PI which is 3 sessions of a 17-session lecture). Since teaching seems like a gap in my resume, I am wondering whether or not it is possible to propose a graduate-level course like "Special Topics in Robotics: X" to the department I am affiliated with, so that, should they accept it, I can present my own course. So, if such a request is reasonable and already heard of,

1- What does a course proposal look like? It would be nice if one can share samples or any resources related to that.

2- My contract is one year. Thus, are north-American departments generally agile enough in processing these proposals so that if I submit my proposal in this fall semester, I can lecture it in the upcoming spring one?

Comment: Warning: don't fall behind in your research by turning your 1-year full-time research contract into half-teaching / half-research. Just be careful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While details will of course depend on the institution, I have seen exactly this done for exactly this reason in a US institution.

Any large research university always has lots of special seminar sessions and special lecture series and such going on. The boundary between "extracurricular research club" and "minimal credit seminar" is often not too large. If you've got a supportive professor, they will likely be able to help you navigate departmental processes.

The other key challenge, however, will be advertising well enough to attract a sufficient number of students to allow the course to run. Typically, there is some minimum number of registrants you need to have, and if you can't get that many students registered the course will be cancelled and you will not get to teach it after all.

Answer (score 5):

That depends on the department. I would just ask. It seems to me a perfectly reasonable request. So asking should be perfectly fine. If anything, it shows that you are proactive in making this postdoc a success for you and the department. There isn't much more we can add.

Since you seem somewhat unsure, it might be a good idea to do a partial course first with an experienced educator followed by your own course.

Answer (score 2):

Most graduate program have special topics courses the contents of which are to be defined by the instructor.

The hard part is to convince the graduate chair that you have material for an entire course at that level, and that you are fit to teach it.

In addition, you will need to clear this with whomever is paying you unless your appointment explicitly states that you are allowed this:  I doubt your nominal boss or bosses will be thrilled to learn you will devote a *significant* fraction of your time to teach/develop a course rather than work on the project you were hired to complete.

Finally, I’m not sure what you’re trying to achieve.  Teaching a course for the first time is very time consuming, and this will certainly affect your research productivity.  Moreover, this isn’t some 1st year course with some canonical textbook we’re talking about, so expect to spend quite a bit of time on this and not much on your research.

Comment: According to my contract, I am authorized to teach a 3-credit course per semester.